# ChromeDriver is not geting the URL I inserted

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I created a maven project. When I run the code using ChromeDriver it opens blank page of chrome and the code stopped:

```
String URL = "https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/" ;
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() ;
        driver.get(URL);
```

I tried using Firefox driver and it works, but ChromeDriver has this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String URL = "https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/" ;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options) ;
driver.get(URL);
```

I added this code and my problem is fixed

Comment: options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"); is suggested 'everywhere on the internet'. Should it be options.addArgument("--remote-allow-origins=*"); Argument, not Arguments